# Remove Data from MongoDb by id and Name?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to remove a Document by id and name?
I have a big Document with one id and i want to remove a specified Document in it by name.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "555edae64d03d5282035228a",
    "name": "Sr1",
    "d1": [
      {
        "name": "testDoc1",
      },
      "d2": [
      {
        "name": "testDoc2",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For example i want to remove only d1.

Comment: Do you mean remove a field from a document or remove the document itself identified by a key/field? And also, can you please provide feedback on the answers to the other questions you have asked on Stack Overflow, they don't have any accepted solutions?

Comment: i want to remove only the field.
can i mark the questions with solved?

Comment: given documents structure not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

**As you state you want to remove `d1` only**, You can use [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) in mongo to remove `d1` from your document.
Query would be like -

```
db.collection.update({"_id":"555edae64d03d5282035228a"},{$unset:{d1:""}})
```

Or by comparing `name` in `d1` array like-

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "555edae64d03d5282035228a",
  "d1": {
    $elemMatch: {
        name: "testDoc1"
    }
  }
}, {
  $unset: {
    d1: ""
  }
})
```